# What are the rules/time-limits to adding a bounty to your question?

Tags: support, bounty

How long do I have to wait before the "Start bounty" button appears on one of my questions? I have a question that hasn't been answered yet and I would like to put a bounty on it, but the button hasn't shown up yet? Are there other rules that apply to when the bounty button appears?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty):

> There are a few other rules around bounties:
>
> - Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty.
> - Users must have at least 75 reputation to offer a bounty.
> - **There can only be 1 active bounty** per question and **per user** at any given time.
> - Once initiated, the bounty period lasts 7 days.
> - After starting a bounty, you must wait 1 day before awarding it.
> - If you do not award your bounty within 7 days, the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is older than 2 days, and there's no button to add bounty to it.

Comment: @daviesgeek which question is it?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22625/problem-with-keyframing-in-final-cut-express-4

Comment: @daviesgeek ah, you can only have 1 bounty at a time http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/7833/daviesgeek?tab=bounties

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering what was happening there! Can you add that to your answer please?

Comment: @daviesgeek Well it was in the list, but I've edited to change the highlighting

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what reported by Kyle Cronin, [users can now have a maximum of 3 active bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/why-cant-a-user-have-simultaneous-bounties-any-more/104813#104813) at any given time. There still the limit of one bounty per question, but you can have three bounties on three different questions, where nobody else offered a bounty already.

The [FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) has been changed to reflect this.